# os module broke python, getting errors for programs I'm not running

Tags: python

I'm doing a udemy programming course and as part of that they had me write this code:

```
import os

listing = os.walk('.')
for root, directories, files in listing:
    print(root)
    for d in directories:
        print(d)
    for file in files:
        print(file)
```

since then, whenever I run any python program, even if it is this:

```
statement_1 = False
statement_2 = True

if statement_1 == True:
    print("Statement 1 is true")
elif statement_2 == True:
    print("Statement 2 is true")
else:
    print("both statements are false")
```

I get this error:
C:\Users\Reinout\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/Users/Reinout/IdeaProjects/Learning projects/**test**.py"
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Reinout\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 73, in 
    import os
  File "C:\Users\Reinout\IdeaProjects\Learning projects\functions**os**.py", line 3, in 
    listing = os.walk('.')
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'walk'

So the question is: why do i get errors for a different program when it doesn't even have anything to do with the program I'm running? I'm not trying to import the os module right now. and even if I was, it definitely does have the attribute 'walk'. I can click on it to see the documentation.

Comment: Is one of your files called "os.py" by any chance?

Comment: Probably because the second line of error indicates that OP does in fact have a file named `os.py` in `C:\Users\Reinout\IdeaProjects\Learning projects\functions`?

Comment: yes, I do. that's the file that contains the first bit of code. 
But even if that one is full of bugs I should still be able to run a second, unrelated program? the second bit of code is all of the code in test.py, there's no importing going on there.

Comment: Python needs to import a bunch of modules to support itself, and the stdlib `os` module is one of them. (`test` is another stdlib module, containing Python's own regression test suite and intended for internal use only, so that's another name you shouldn't use for your own code.)

Comment: oh! right. the problem was the name I gave the file, not the code in it. I deleted the file and now everything works fine again. thanks for the help!